# How to cast uiviewcontroller to custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

I have a list custom `viewController`

```
NSMutableArray *arrOfCtrls = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
AViewController *aCtrl = [[AViewController alloc] init];
BViewController *bCtrl = [[BViewController alloc] init];
CViewController *cCtrl = [[CViewController alloc] init];
DViewController *dCtrl = [[DViewController alloc] init];
[arrOfCtrls addObject: aCtrl];
[arrOfCtrls addObject: bCtrl];
[arrOfCtrls addObject: cCtrl];
[arrOfCtrls addObject: dCtrl];
```

And then, i want to get `UIViewController` in list **arrOfCtrls**

```
UIViewController *vCtrl = arrOfCtrls[0];
```

How to cast vCtrl is `AViewController` ?
I want to get properties in vCtrl, Example i want to get aProperties in AViewController

```
vCtrl.aProperties
```

Thanks!

Comment: `AViewController *vCtr = (AViewController *)arrOfCtrls[0];`

Comment: use `((AViewController *)arrOfCtrls[0])`?

Comment: I dont know vCtr is AViewController. How to reconizge vCtr is AViewController

Answer (score 4):

If you know that first object is type of `AViewController` then you direct cast using this

```
AViewController *aVC = (AViewController*)arrOfCtrls[0];
```

If you don't know and want to cast check like this

```
AViewController *aVC; 
if ([arrOfCtrls[0] isKindOfClass:[AViewController class]]) { 
    aVC = arrOfCtrls[0];
}
```

Comment: You don't need the cast at all since `arrOfCtrls[0]` is of type `id`.

Comment: I dont want if else. i want to cast UIViewController to AViewController

Comment: The answer is present check that in first line

Comment: @Takashi Are you getting what i say ?

Comment: @Takashi You posted a comment below the question stating that you don't know that `arrOfCtrls[0]` is a AViewController and you want to know how to recognize that it is. Then in a comment below this answer you state you don't want an `if/else`. You can't have both. If you don't know what type of view controller it represents, then you need an `if/else` to determine its type so you can properly assign the value and access the specific properties.

Comment: @Takashi . can you explain, how you resolved it? I'm not getting the answer.